# Sci-fi animated TV-series about a post asteroid impact on Earth

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched this cartoon in the '90s or early 2000s and believe that it is American. I remember that the story was about the world after an asteroid impact. An important detail is that uranium/plutonium somehow stops working, thus no nuclear power. Therefore, there was always a struggle for energy.

There was a kind of world government with strong governors (maybe on continental level). However, some evil warlord with its rebels (in red, maybe) ruled in a forbidden zone. The last thing I remember is that the protagonist (I forgot about him) discovered that another impact might occur soon.

Sorry for the few details but I looked in all blogs, wikis and IMDb lists and cannot find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Chris Colorado*, a French animated TV series that aired from 2000.

[image: Show Poster for Chris Colorado]

[Wikipedia synopsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Colorado):

> Chris Colorado takes place on an apocalyptic future Earth. After a data-processing bug prevents mankind from detecting the fall of a meteorite, it results in the destruction of nearly all life on Earth in a massive disaster later known as The Great Crash. After some time, many groups of survivors gathered together to try to rebuild and create a newer, more peaceful society, and formed "The World Federation". After several decades of peace, a mysterious dictator called Thanatos, a human wearing a helmet to conceal his face, with an army of humans converted into cyborgs called Thanors, started The Mega War, which ended with Thanatos taking control of Europe. However one group, "The Centurions of Freedom", led by Commander Richard Julian, succeeded in striking back and defeating Thanatos, who seemed to take refuge in what remained of Glorious City (Earth's first world capital, now mostly destroyed by the meteorite) where a strange black liquid from the meteorite, now called "Dark Torrent" by the Centurions, enabled him to recruit a new army of Thanors out of the survivors still living in the ruins of the city and start a constant skirmish-war against the World Federation.

The [TV Tropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ChrisColorado) mentions nuclear power not working anymore:

> **Unobtainium**: Magnetite, but not really. Since the meteor fell, nuclear power does not work anymore, and magnet reactors of some kind are used to generate power. The world capital is at Chichen Itza, where a new magnetic pole of the Earth was located.

### Opening Credits

Comment: Bingo! I found a mention of nuclear power not working, and edited that in as well as editing out your statement that there's no mention of nuclear power. I hope you don't mind. Good find!

Comment: I don't mind. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Give me another 23 hours, and you'll get a bounty. This really was a nice catch.

Comment: Thanks again! :D

Comment: ^_^ Enjoy the bounty!

Comment: OMG....you found it!!! awesome. you got no idea how long I was looking for that. THX.

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 10):

This might be a long shot, since I feel like it has details you would have thought more prominent than energy concerns, but could this be *[Highlander: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander:_The_Animated_Series)*?

> The story unfolds on post-apocalyptic Earth, after a meteorite collision nearly wipes out all human civilization after setting off nuclear weapons. Following this catastrophe, Connor MacLeod (the protagonist of the original film) and the other Immortals forswear the Game of fighting each other until only one Immortal remains to win the Prize. Instead, the Immortals swear to preserve human knowledge and help humanity. They cast away their swords and call themselves Jettators (from the French jette, "thrown away".)
>
> But one Immortal, Kortan, refuses to swear the oath, he still seeks the Prize and now wishes to dominate the world. Connor challenges Kortan to a duel and is defeated and killed, as any Immortal who breaks the oath is destined to die. However, with Connor's death comes the prophecy of the rise of a new Immortal, unbound by the oath, who will defeat Kortan. Uncontested by the Jettators and nigh-unkillable by mortals, Kortan establishes an empire controlling most of the planet, which he rules from his fortress Mogonda.

As with the original movies, the central conceit is immortals battling it out with swords, but another recurring concern is powering society, with certain immortals hording the secrets of hydroelectric, or nuclear, power. And, as noted in the summary, it is a post-apocalyptic Earth caused by a meteorite collision, and it has warlords.

### Intro and Credits

I found this series by searching for `cartoon series asteroid "nuclear power" stops working`. I have not personally watched it.

Comment: That *actually* sounds like a reasonably good conceit for a quality action-adventure show. Not something I expect from movie spin-offs. Kinda guessing it flubbed the execution, just because as a spin-off it seems like it must have failed somewhere along the line.

Comment: @KRyan: I haven't watched more than a few minutes on Youtube, but based on the first episode, they didn't budget a lot for animation or voice-acting. And summaries of the series indicate that it had a serious problem with lack of progress. The protagonist gained all sorts of new power and skills, but it never actually changed anything.

Comment: What's the deal with bad guys and ear muffs? First Darkseid, now this guy.

Comment: Sorry but it is NOT right. The Highlander is always amongst the most mentioned cartoons from that time. The cartoon I mean is really obscure. I know that it is a stretch to find it with so few details....it is just so annoying not to find it. The dysfunctional nuclear power is kind of the key...