# Cartoon series that I watched around 2005 with red robotic humans in white masks

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots

If they took off their masks and pushed a button on their temples, they died/deactivated. Can't remember anything else, but they where expendable, so literally "redshirts".

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like the Thanors from *Chris Colorado*. From the TV Tropes entry for [Cyanide Pill](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CyanidePill):

[image: Image of the Thanors]

> Thanors have literal kill switches installed behind their ears and are seen using them in some episodes.

### Kill switch example at 13:15

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193470/sci-fi-animated-tv-series-about-a-post-asteroid-impact-on-earth